# Auto perspective correction using OpenCV 4.1.1 and Java

Tags: java

I have successfully detected the largest rectangle from the image but since my application will be used for the scanning purpose ,i want to have the perspective change functionality as well.

Comment: reworked version

Comment: Show some code. Show what you have tried. More info here: [ask]

Comment: I have no idea at all what this question is about

Answer (score -1):

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    String default_file = "D:/folder name/image.jpg";
    String filename = ((args.length > 0) ? args[0] : default_file);
    //  Mat imgSource = Highgui.imread(fileName, Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
    Mat imgSource = Imgcodecs.imread(filename, Imgcodecs.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    // Check if image is loaded fine
    if( imgSource.empty() ) {
        System.out.println("Error opening image!");
        System.out.println("Program Arguments: [image_name -- default "
                + default_file +"] \n");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    Imgproc.Canny(imgSource.clone(), imgSource, 50, 50);

    // apply gaussian blur to smoothen lines of dots
    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(imgSource, imgSource, new org.opencv.core.Size(5, 5), 5);

    // find the contours
    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
    Imgproc.findContours(imgSource, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    double maxArea = -1;
    MatOfPoint temp_contour = contours.get(0); // the largest is at the
    // index 0 for starting
    // point
    MatOfPoint2f approxCurve = new MatOfPoint2f();

    for (int idx = 0; idx < contours.size(); idx++) {
        temp_contour = contours.get(idx);
        double contourarea = Imgproc.contourArea(temp_contour);
        // compare this contour to the previous largest contour found
        if (contourarea > maxArea) {
            // check if this contour is a square
            MatOfPoint2f new_mat = new MatOfPoint2f(temp_contour.toArray());
            int contourSize = (int) temp_contour.total();
            MatOfPoint2f approxCurve_temp = new MatOfPoint2f();
            Imgproc.approxPolyDP(new_mat, approxCurve_temp, contourSize * 0.05, true);
            if (approxCurve_temp.total() == 4) {
                maxArea = contourarea;
                approxCurve = approxCurve_temp;
            }
        }
    }

    Imgproc.cvtColor(imgSource, imgSource, Imgproc.COLOR_BayerBG2RGB);
    Mat sourceImage = Imgcodecs.imread(filename, Imgcodecs.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    double[] temp_double;
    temp_double = approxCurve.get(0, 0);
    Point p1 = new Point(temp_double[0], temp_double[1]);

    temp_double = approxCurve.get(1, 0);
    Point p2 = new Point(temp_double[0], temp_double[1]);

    temp_double = approxCurve.get(2, 0);
    Point p3 = new Point(temp_double[0], temp_double[1]);

    temp_double = approxCurve.get(3, 0);
    Point p4 = new Point(temp_double[0], temp_double[1]);

    List<Point> source = new ArrayList<Point>();
    source.add(p1);
    source.add(p2);
    source.add(p3);
    source.add(p4);
    Mat startM = Converters.vector_Point2f_to_Mat(source);
    Mat result = warp(sourceImage, startM);



  HighGui.imshow("Source", result);
   // Wait and Exit
    HighGui.waitKey();
    System.exit(0);
   // System.out.println(p1);
}

public static Mat warp(Mat inputMat, Mat startM) {

    int resultWidth = 1550;
    int resultHeight = 700;

    Point ocvPOut4 = new Point(0, 0);
    Point ocvPOut1 = new Point(0, resultHeight);
    Point ocvPOut2 = new Point(resultWidth, resultHeight);
    Point ocvPOut3 = new Point(resultWidth, 0);

    if (inputMat.height() > inputMat.width()) {
        // int temp = resultWidth;
        // resultWidth = resultHeight;
        // resultHeight = temp;

        ocvPOut3 = new Point(0, 0);
        ocvPOut4 = new Point(0, resultHeight);
        ocvPOut1 = new Point(resultWidth, resultHeight);
        ocvPOut2 = new Point(resultWidth, 0);
    }

    Mat outputMat = new Mat(resultWidth, resultHeight, CvType.CV_8UC4);

    List<Point> dest = new ArrayList<Point>();
    dest.add(ocvPOut1);
    dest.add(ocvPOut2);
    dest.add(ocvPOut3);
    dest.add(ocvPOut4);

    Mat endM = Converters.vector_Point2f_to_Mat(dest);

    Mat perspectiveTransform = Imgproc.getPerspectiveTransform(startM, endM);
   // System.out.println(dest);

    Imgproc.warpPerspective(inputMat, outputMat, perspectiveTransform, new Size(resultWidth, resultHeight), Imgproc.INTER_CUBIC);

    return outputMat;
}
```

}